# Как правильно отфильтровать список с стриме по сложным условиям?

Tags: java, java-stream

У меня есть такой список: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 5, 8, 2]`. Требуется отфильровать его так, чтобы в нем остались только числа, которые входят в него более одного раза. То есть, он должен превратиться в такой: `[2, 4]`. Сделать это необходимо с помощью Java Stream API.

На ум приходит такое решение, но сдается мне, что оно не самое оптимальное и красивое:

```
List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 5, 8, 2);
List<Integer> result = input
        .stream()
        .filter(x -> input.stream().filter(x::equals).count() > 1)
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Можно ли как-то скрыть стрим в стриме и сделать это более адекватно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С точки зрения читабельности - на любителя... Но насчет эффективности, вроде получше будет так:

```
List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 5, 8, 2);
List<Integer> result = input.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() > 1)
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> result = input.stream()
                .distinct()
                .filter(i -> input.indexOf(i) != input.lastIndexOf(i))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Интересное поведение `distinct`. Получается, что оно применяется уже после фильтра, не смотря на то, что используется ДО...

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець почему после? Вроде все по порядку.

Comment: Тогда как фильтр после distinct знает, что некоторых значений больше одного?

Comment: С чего вы взяли  что disctinct() не отсекает дубликаты сразу? Поставьте после него peek() и проверьте.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець он не знает, в фильтре мы заглядываем в изначальный список, который не поменялся.